# Split a list into smaller lists

Tags: python

i have a list that has strings in it
for example

```
list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
```

i would like to make it into smaller lists inside that list. each list is the words that have the same letters for example:

```
list_of_words = [['deltas', 'desalt', 'salted'], ['generating', 'greatening']]
```

im trying to think about a code that could help me but what i came out with gives me alot of errors or just won't work.

Comment: can you provide the code that does not work and a trceback of the errors?

Comment: Also .. what is the criteria for the new lists?

Comment: Is the order important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` shouldn't be used when you need sorting first (too high complexity), even if the temptation to create a one-liner is great.

A better way in that case is with `defaultdict(list)`, with the sorted tuple of letters as key.

```
import collections

list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for l in list_of_words:
    d[tuple(sorted(l))].append(l)
```

(or `d["".join(sorted(l))].append(l)` to get keys a string)

which results in the dictionary:

```
{('a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 's', 't'): ['deltas',
                                  'desalt',
                                  'slated',
                                  'salted',
                                  'staled',
                                  'lasted'],
 ('a', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'): ['generating', 'greatening'],
 ('a', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'r', 's', 't'): ['retainers', 'ternaries'],
 ('a', 'n', 'p', 's', 't'): ['pants'],
 ('e', 'l', 'm', 'r', 's', 't'): ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']}
```

Comment: Thank you! took me sometime to understand your code but once i did i see how easy it was and how dumb i was.
Thanks agian!

Answer (score 2):

Another use case for `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 
                 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening',
                 'lasted', 'resmelts']

list_of_words.sort(key=sorted)
output = [list(words) for _, words in groupby(list_of_words, key=sorted)]
print(output)

#  [['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'], 
#   ['generating', 'greatening'], ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], 
#   ['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more bloated code than the early answers, but also slightly more readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']

def getAnagrams(source):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in source:
        key = "".join(sorted(word))
        d[key].append(word)
    return d

anagrams = getAnagrams(list_of_words)

separated_list = list(anagrams.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
print(list_of_words)
srt = []

print("\n-----------------------")

def sorted_gett_letter(word):
    sorted_letters = ''.join(sorted(word))
    return sorted_letters

for word in list_of_words:
    foobar=sorted_gett_letter(word)
    srt.append(foobar)


print(srt)
print("\n-----------------------")

set_srt = set(sorted(srt))
print(set_srt)
list_of_set_srt = list(set_srt)
list_container = []

for subdiv in set_srt:
    print(subdiv)
    list_container.append(list())


print(list_container)


for word in list_of_words:  
    word_index_in_set = list_of_set_srt.index(sorted_gett_letter(word))
    print(word_index_in_set)
    list_container[word_index_in_set].append(word)

print("\n-----------------------")

print(list_container)
```